# data-binding Spring

Tags: java, spring, data-binding

I have a Contact object that I put in the request, this object is modified in the
form and then get the modified object. I would like the object that is back is the same object that you send, you keep the value of the attributes that were not in the form.

```
class Contact{

     private String name;          // this attributes will be modified
     private String lastName;

     private Long id;
     private Date created;        // this atributes will not be modified

     // getters and setters ....

}


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateContact(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {

         Contact c = contactDao.get(id);
         model.addAttribute("contact", c);

         return "contact/form";

    }



     @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute Contact contact, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        // The contact I get here I want to keep the original attributes of the
       // object sent, and have the changes in the fields shown on the form. is that possible?

        return "redirect:/contact";
  }


   <form:form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/tags/create"            commandName="contact">

              <form:input path="name"/>
              <form:errors path="name" cssClass="formError"/>
              <form:input path="lastName"/>

   </form:form>
```

I do not want to use hidden fields to maintain the value of the attributes that will not be changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem by stating the contact object as an object that lives in the session

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contact")  
@SessionAttributes("contact")
public class ContactController {

....
....


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateContact(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {

        Contact c = contactDao.get(id);
        model.addAttribute("contact", c);
        return "contact/form";

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute Contact contact, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        contactDao.update(contact);

        return "redirect:/contact";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want some of the fields to be handled in a form, make a new class - ContactDTO that contains only them, and then manually (or through reflection) copy them to the original `Contact` object (which you load by id from the DB)

Comment: that's what I'm doing, and I do not

Answer (score -1):

What is your persistence framework? is it JPA or Hibernate? If so, annotate the field with **@Column(updatable=false)**